# How can I find if a function is in the list (Python)

Tags: python

I have a **list of functions** that are saved, but not ran. 

I need to iterate through this list and see if one of the items i'm looking for exists in the list.

How can I do this?

Here's how the functions are being stored.

```
self.pysat_fun.set_fun_list(self.pysat_fun.set_file_outpath)  # add this function to the pysat list to be run

def set_fun_list(self, fun, replacelast=False):
    if replacelast:
        self.fun_list[-1] = fun
    else:
        self.fun_list.append(fun)
```

Below you can see what is contained inside the list.
[image]

Here's my attempt.

```
    for i in range(0, len(self.fun_list)):
        if pysat_func.do_norm in self.fun_list:
            print("True")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(self.leftOff, len(self.fun_list)):
    if pysat_func.do_norm == self.fun_list [i]:
        print("True")
        break
```

Or, briefly:

```
print (pysat_func.do_norm in self.fun_list [self.leftOff : ])
```

Which works as follows:

```
self.fun_list
```

is the list in which you want to search for your function.

```
self.fun_list [self.leftOff : ]
```

is the tail of that list, since from your original code it seems
you only want to search from element with index `self.leftOff`.

```
[self.leftOff : ]
```

is called a slice, the blank behind the : means 'until the end'.

```
pysat_func.do_norm in aList
```

is a boolean expression that evaluates to `True` if and only if `pysat_func.do_norm` is in `aList`

so

```
pysat_func.do_norm in self.fun_list [self.leftOff : ]
```

is a boolean expression that evaluates to `True` if and only if
`pysat_func.do_norm` is in the tail that I talked about

```
print (anyThing)
```

will print anything inside its braces, which happens to be the above mentioned `True` (or `False`).

An example of which bound methods are in a certain list and which ones aren't:

```
class A:
    def f (self):
        print ('f')

    def g (self):
        print ('g')

a1 = A ()
a2 = A () 

aList = [a1.f, a2.g]

print (
    a1.f in aList,
    a1.g in aList,
    a2.f in aList,
    a2.g in aList
)
```

prints:

```
True False False True
```

Comment: Weird. It's printing out false when i use your print function

Comment: the print needs to be outside of the for loop right? `print (pysat_func.do_norm in self.fun_list [self.leftOff : ])`

Comment: Since you're looking only for one function (if I understand right) the print in the first code block is at the right spot. If you found your function, the break will jump out of the loop. The second code block ought to be equivalent to the first. Are you sure you're indeed storing BOUND functions? So object_a.do_norm is different from object_b.do_norm? Looking to an old question you posed, you aren't by any chance storing lambda's? Maybe show some context code.

Comment: Edited. Please let me know if that's enough or not

Comment: It is enough, and your search loop is correct, but without the `break` you keep on searching your list to the end, even if you already found the function. And in `print (pysat_func.do_norm in self.fun_list [self.leftOff : ])` the `print` isn't outside any loop, there's no loop needed. But as said, your search loop is correct as well, though a bit verbose.

Comment: This is really messing with my head. Could you explain a little more what is happening under the hood with the print function returning True or False?

Comment: Will put in in an [EDIT]